# $\sqrt {e ^{2 \pi i}} = 1$ or $-1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\sqrt{e^{2\pi i}}  = \sqrt{1} = 1  $$

However,

$$(e^{2\pi i})^\frac {1}{2} = e^{\pi i} = -1$$

By substituting $e$ for $\lim_{x\to 0} (1 + 1/x)^x$, it proves that the result in the first equation is accurate. Hence, I would like to know what is wrong with the second equation.

Comment: every nonzero complex number has two square roots...

Comment: It's equal to both. Square roots are not uniquely defined. Indeed, there are $n$-many non-equal $n^{th}$ roots of any complex number, for $n$ an integer.

Comment: But one could argue that the immediate result is real and then the positive root has to be taken (at least I would handle it this way)

Comment: $\sqrt{1}=1$ or $-1$?

Comment: (More formally, $e^{2\pi i+2k\pi}=1$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. So what happens when you apply the power of $1/2$?

Comment: @AntonGrudkin I would vote for "$1$" , as said.

Comment: My understanding of why the first equation is accurate came from https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/3vnkoo/eli5_why_e2pii_1/.

Comment: First, $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=1\ne e$.  And I'm not sure what this would have to do with the square root.  Second, we have $z^C\equiv e^{C\log(z)}=e^{C\log(|z|)+iC\arg(z)}$.  With $C=\frac12$ and $|z|=1$, and $\arg(z)=2n\pi$, we have $(z)^{1/2}=e^{\frac12\log(|1|)+i\frac12 (2n\pi)}=e^{0+in\pi}=e^{in\pi}$.  If $n$ is even, the square root is $1$; if $n$ is odd the square root is $-1$.

Comment: **Why is everyone jumping all over the OP with downvotes and close votes?** All the criteria of a good question have been met! I rhetorically ask you if you have to be a mathematical pro to ask well-received questions here? Shame on all of you for discouraging a new user without offering any suggestions or pointers. **Welcome to the community, ILTJ.**

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I agree. But apparently it is inevitable that some questions are unjustified down-/closevoted , but other question and the corresponding answers are upvoted "to heaven" unjustified as well.

Comment: Additionally, a better feeling for question definitely showing no effort and for interesting question where the author is not able to give the expected effort, would be nice. I often witnessed wrong handling in both directions : On the one hand, troll-questions survive relatively long because the users seem to be amused by the trolling. On the other hand, interesting questions are thrown away because of missing effort which is correct in most, but not in all cases. What I would find nice as well - less links to youtube-videos or similar commercial math-sites.

Answer (score 2):

That depends upon the meaning of $\sqrt{\ }$:

- If, when $a\in[0,+\infty)$, $\sqrt a$ is the only non-negative square root of $a$, then, since $e^{2\pi i}=1$, the answer is $1$.
- If $\sqrt a$ is *a* square root of $a$ (a bad choice of notation), then both answers are correct, since both $1$ and $-1$ are square roots of $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $\sqrt x$ as a complex function, then you have two sqaure roots of $1$ namely  $\pm1$.

If you just write $\sqrt 1$ then it is $1$ and if you want $-1$ you write $-\sqrt 1$

Answer (score 0):

Technically, both are correct.
You could ask he question:
$$\sqrt{9} \stackrel{?}{=} 3 \ \text{or}\ \sqrt{9} \stackrel{?}{=} -3$$
Since the square root symbol asks the question: "What number raised to the second power results in this number?"

And since $3^2 = 9$ and $(-3)^2 =9$, both could be accepted as the correct answer.

However, in mathematics, we have defined $\sqrt{\ \ }$ to be a funtion with a $1$ to $1$ correspondance, so we define $\sqrt{x^2} := |x|$, and not $\sqrt{x^2} :\ne -|x|$. But when expanding on the idea of $\sqrt{\ \ }$, this can be quite misleading, so in the case of complex numbers, we have to go back to the notion of $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm |x|$.